# How to handle shadow DOM inside iframe with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, iframe, puppeteer, shadow-dom

I want to click a button in a shadow DOM inside an iframe. Is there a way to do this?

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <iframe class="iframe_1">
      #document    
        <div class="shadow-root">
          #shadow-root (open)
          <div>
            <button id="btn_1"></button>
            <button id="btn_2"></button>
          </div>
    </iframe>
  </body>
  </body>
```

I did this:

```
const frameHandle = await page.$("iframe.iframe_1");
const frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame();
var button = await frame.querySelector(".shadow-root").shadowRoot.querySelector("button[id='btn_1']");
await button.click();
```

But got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: frame.querySelector is not a function
```

I know why this error has occurred, but I can't come up with other ideas. Please teach me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you're trying to call `frame.querySelector`, but `querySelector` is not a function that exists on `frame`. `DOMElement#querySelector` is defined in the browser only, which you can access via a frame using an evaluate-family call.

For example, if you want to return an element, you can use `evaluateHandle`:

```js
const button = await frame.evaluateHandle(() =>
  document.querySelector(".shadow-root")
    .shadowRoot
    .querySelector("#btn_1")
);
```

Going a step further, instead of dipping into the root by hand with `evaluateHandle`, you can use `>>>`:

```js
const button = await frame.$(">>> #btn_1");
```

Here's a minimal, complete example you can run and see in action on your provided DOM structure:

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
  <iframe class="iframe_1"></iframe>
<script>
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <div class="shadow-root"></div>
<script>
  const el = document.querySelector(".shadow-root");
  const root = el.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
  el.shadowRoot.innerHTML = \`
    <button id="btn_1">A</button>
    <button id="btn_2">B</button>
  \`;
  el.shadowRoot.querySelector("#btn_1").addEventListener("click", event => {
    event.target.textContent = "clicked";
  });
<\/script>
`;
const doc = document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(html);
doc.close();
</script>
</body></html>
```

`index.js`:

```js
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.11.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const html = (await fs.readFile("index.html")).toString();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const frameHandle = await page.$("iframe.iframe_1");
  const frame = await frameHandle.contentFrame();
  const button = await frame.$(">>> #btn_1");
  await button.click();
  const result = await button.evaluate(el => el.textContent);
  console.log(result); // => clicked
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```